# Why do neural networks have layers instead of being a sea of freely connected neurons?

Tags: neural-networks

What I mean is, neural networks are neatly sectioned off into layers. But why? Why not just make a sea of neurons that all connect to each other, then let them sort out their weights and connections on their own? Is it just that doing that is too difficult, or did somebody try it and prove it's a bad idea?